# Converting byte to int

Tags: visual-c++, arrays

so I have a Bytearray `BYTE dataOut[3]` with the following data which I send out to a device.

```
unsigned int value = 512;
BYTE low_byte = 0xff & value;
BYTE high_byte = value >> 8;

dataOut[0]=SET_POSITION; //predefined
dataOut[1]=low_byte;
dataOut[2]=high_byte;
```

The device executes the command in this data packet. Then I call a read function which populates `BYTE dataIn[3]` with data of the same format. How can I convert the bytes in `dataIn[1]` and `dataIn[2]` into an int value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
value = (unsigned int)dataIn[2] << 8 + (unsigned int)dataIn[1]
```

should do it....